# Why can't I obtain a FileChannel from a FileWriter?

Tags: java, io

I'm wandering why getChannel is only implemented in FileOutputStream and not in FileWriter.

Is there any true reason ? Is there a way to lock a FileWriter another way ?

thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect it is an oversight - note that `FileWriter` is a subclass of `OutputStreamWriter` that does nothing except pass a `FileOutputStream` to the superclass constructor.

Note also that you should almost never use `FileWriter` since it does not allow you to specify the encoding. Instead, "manually" wrap a `FileOutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` - then you can also obtain the corresponding channel for locking.